# Why do I get a negative value for this integral?

Tags: calculus, integration

I am trying to compute the integral: $$\int_{4}^{5} \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^{2}-16}}$$
The question is related to hyperbolic functions, so I let $x = 4\cosh(u)$ therefore the integral becomes: $$-\int_{0}^{\ln(2)}\frac{4\sinh(u)}{\sqrt{16-16\cosh^{2}(u)}}du = -\int_{0}^{\ln(2)}1du = -\ln(2)$$

The answer is $\ln(2)$ so if someone could point out where I went wrong that would be great, thanks

Comment: Where did the minus sign in front come from? The derivative of $\cosh$ is $\sinh$. And what is $16-16\cosh^2 u$ doing under the square root sign? It is mostly negative.

Comment: Ah, I simply wrote down the relation between $\cosh$ and $\sinh$ wrong, sorry! I looked over checking that because that was the simple part

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Setting $x = 4 \cosh(u)$, gives us $dx = 4 \sinh(u)du$. Hence the integral becomes
$$\int_0^{\ln(2)} \dfrac{4 \sinh(u) du}{\sqrt{16\cosh^2(u) - 16}} = \int_0^{\ln(2)} \dfrac{4 \sinh(u) du}{4 \sinh(u)} = \ln(2)$$

Answer (score 1):

use this formula
$$\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^{2}-a^2}}=\log|x+\sqrt{x^2-a^2}|+c$$
$$\int_{4}^{5} \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^{2}-16}}$$
$$\int_{4}^{5} \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^{2}-4^2}}$$
$$(\log|x+\sqrt{x^2-16}|)_4 ^5$$
$$\log|8|-\log|4|$$
$$\log2$$